# How to select and get the value of non empty text area fields in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple textareas. What is i want to do that to select those textareas which is not empty and get there text values using jQuery. But couldn't. The sample is given below:

```
<div class="item">
    <textarea class="col-sm-10 comment">TextArea1</textarea>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <textarea class="col-sm-10 comment">TextArea2</textarea>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <textarea class="col-sm-10 comment">TextArea3</textarea>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <textarea class="col-sm-10 comment"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <textarea class="col-sm-10 comment"></textarea>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.comment').filter(function(){
     var test = $.trim($(this).val());
     if(test.length==0){
        console.log(test);
     }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
var TextValues = [];
$(".comment").each(function(){
    if($(this).val()){
        console.log($(this).val());
        TextValues.push($(this).val());
    }
});
```

Comment: Its worked...thank you very much...can you please give me a slight brief about why filter didn't work but each did...

Comment: I think is not because `filter`, but the `if` you are doing... Look's like `test.lenght` is never being `0`

Answer (score 1):

You can filter it as you're doing and then return the text values.

```
var textAreas = $('.comment').filter(function(){
    var test = $.trim($(this).val());
    return test.length !== 0;
}).map(function(i, el) {
    return $(el).text();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```
$('.comment').each(function(){
     var test = $(this).val();
     if(test.length!=0){
        console.log(test);
     }
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Micio/4whtzbnw/)